# insert sqlquery with currDate() + 1

Tags: mysql

// This is what i'm trying to do.

```
insert into " + cityName + "_salesdeliveryslots(deliverydate,slotno,timedorders,addedon) "
                            + " values(DATE_ADD(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS saleDeliveryDate, ?,?,Str_To_Date(? ,'%d-%m-%y'));";



int verify  =   jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {date,slot,"1",date});
```

// anyone who can correct it ?

Comment: provide your complete code

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Answer (score 0):

use following which will give next date

```
cast(curdate() + 1 as date)
```